# How to pass an object type with python in a stored procedure as IN OUT parameter

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, django-models

i have a legacy datamodel with three schemas. data, view and api. The tables are stored in data, views in views and stored procs in api. Now i want to use django to build an app for it. In the api i have procedures with custom types as arguments to store the data, write the history and take care about user rights and logging.

I made a model which is not managed by Django and try to overwrite the save method:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class Mandator(models.Model):
    mdt_id          = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mdt_guid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,
                                editable=False)
    mdt_name        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mdt_insert_date = models.DateField()
    mdt_insert_user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mdt_update_date = models.DateField()
    mdt_update_user = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'fdb_mandator'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc('prc_fdb_mandator_insert',[self])
```

When i execute the save method, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/*****/Workspaces/FlexDB/flexdb-django/flexdb/fmgr/models/mandator.py", line 19, in save
    cursor.callproc('prc_fdb_mandator_insert',[self])
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in callproc
    return self.cursor.callproc(procname, params, kparams)
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in callproc
    return self.cursor.callproc(procname, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Mandator'
```

The database is an PostreSQL 12!

The type:

```
create type fdb_mandator_ot as
(
    mdt_id          integer,
    mdt_guid        uuid,
    mdt_name        varchar(255),
    mdt_insert_date date,
    mdt_insert_user varchar(255),
    mdt_update_date date,
    mdt_update_user varchar(255)
);
```

The procedure skeleton:

```
create procedure prc_fdb_mandator_insert(INOUT p_mdt fdb_mandator_ot, p_username character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    l_prc_name  VARCHAR := 'prc_fdb_mandator_insert';
BEGIN
    .
    .
    .
END;
$$;
```

With the code:

```
cursor.execute('CALL prc_fdb_mandator_insert(fdb_mandator_ot(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))',
                            [self.mdt_id, 
                             None, 
                             self.mdt_name, 
                             self.mdt_insert_date, 
                             self.mdt_insert_user, 
                             self.mdt_update_date, 
                             self.mdt_update_user])
```

there is no error, but in the database is no new entry ...

With:

```
cursor.execute('''DO
                  $$
                  DECLARE
                      l_mdt   fdb_mandator_ot;
                  BEGIN
                      l_mdt.mdt_id := %s;
                      l_mdt.mdt_name := %s;
 
                      CALL prc_fdb_mandator_insert(l_mdt);
 
                  END;
                  $$''',[self.mdt_id, self.mdt_name])
```

the data is in the DB, but no OUT parameter (mdt_id is null) and very hard to write ...

Did anybody know how i can pass an object type to an stored procedure with python?

Comment: First the model is managed by Django, it is the table that is not. Second what is prc_fdb_mandator_insert() expecting as input/parameter?  Third what language is prc_fdb_mandator_insert written in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The procedure expects a custom type. Its declared as INOUT. The procedure is written in plpgsql. I've edited the post and added the code of the type and the procedure.

Comment: See now that mdt_guid is missing in the Django model. But this could not be the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong brackets. But no have another error. Updated the question ...

Comment: Procedures can't return anything so I'm not sure how you expect to use OUT.  If you want to return values you need to use a function. Not sure why no entry. Though generally if there are no errors(did you look in the Postgres log?)  but no entry it means there was no ```COMMIT```. Without seeing the rest of the procedure it difficult to say anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have now a working solution. I wrote a wrapper function and make the call in the following way:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            if self.mdt_id:
                query = "SELECT * FROM fnc_fdb_mandator_update(ROW(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))"
            else:
                query = "SELECT * FROM fnc_fdb_mandator_insert(ROW(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s))"

            cursor.execute(query,
                           [self.mdt_id,
                            self.mdt_guid,
                            self.mdt_name,
                            self.mdt_insert_date,
                            self.mdt_insert_user,
                            self.mdt_update_date,
                            self.mdt_update_user])
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            self.mdt_id = row[0]
            self.mdt_guid = row[1]
            self.mdt_name = row[2]
            self.mdt_insert_date = row[3]
            self.mdt_insert_user = row[4]
            self.mdt_update_date = row[5]
```

Testausgabe auf der Django shell:

```
>>> from fmgr.models import Mandator
>>> m=Mandator()
>>> m.mdt_name="Test Mandator 1"
>>> 
>>> print(m.mdt_id)
None
>>> print(m.mdt_name)
Test Mandator 1
>>> print(m.mdt_guid)
5e8b7baa-8be9-485e-8c8f-99c18153120b
>>> print(m.mdt_insert_date)
None
>>> print(m.mdt_update_date)
None
>>> 
>>> m.save()
>>> print(m.mdt_id)
2
>>> print(m.mdt_name)
Test Mandator 1
>>> print(m.mdt_guid)
5e8b7baa-8be9-485e-8c8f-99c18153120b
>>> print(m.mdt_insert_date)
2020-07-01
>>> print(m.mdt_update_date)
None
>>> 
>>> m.mdt_name="Test Mandator 111"
>>> m.save()
>>> print(m.mdt_id)
2
>>> print(m.mdt_name)
Test Mandator 111
>>> print(m.mdt_guid)
5e8b7baa-8be9-485e-8c8f-99c18153120b
>>> print(m.mdt_insert_date)
2020-07-01
>>> print(m.mdt_update_date)
2020-07-01
```